# skype cannot connect, What should I do?

Tags: skype

I have an error in Skype that says that Skype cannot connect. I tried reinstalling  Skype but it did not work. I used following commands:

```
rm -rf .Skype
sudo apt-get remove skype
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Answer (score 2):

Did the message read something like

```
server connect failed
```

? Then the problem is that old clients can no longer be used. What version are you running? I experienced this problem myself a few days ago (3rd August 2014) and had to upgrade. My upgrade was from 2.2.0.35-1 to 4.3.0.37-1 (Debian 7.6 wheezy). Upgrading fixed the issue. Also, I had been having intermittent sound problems, and this upgrade made them go away, which was nice.

From [Wikipedia's Skype Protocol page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_protocol):

> On June 20, 2014, Microsoft announced the deprecation of the old Skype
>   protocol. Within several months from this date in order to continue
>   using Skype services Skype users will have to update to Skype
>   applications released in 2014. Older Skype versions (clients) will not
>   be able to log in.

See also this question: [skype version spoofing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/148076/4671)

Comment: Experienced similar thing yesterday myself. Just updating the Skype helped.

Comment: The message is: Skype cannot connect

Comment: @user3271929 What is your Skype release/version number, please?

Comment: skype 4.2 for linux

Comment: @user3271929 Try to upgrade to 4.3.

Comment: @FaheemMitha how I can make?

Comment: @user3271929 how can you what? upgrade? just download the deb from the Skype site, and run `dpkg -i`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it does not include linux version mint

Comment: @user3271929 Try the debian/ubuntu one, depending whether your mint is based on debian or ubuntu. See also http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/skype